# How can I synchronize animations on multiple views which does not start their respective animation at the same time?

Tags: java, android

I wrote a fade in fade out method for views. It works perfectly, but, as I understand, each view's animation is handled by a separate thread in the background, tackled by the android system.

That is a problem, because, I want to blink and the same pace.

Is it possible to do that? I tried to put my blinking method in a runnable and restart it every time a new View starts its animation, but it is not working because 1. you cannot simply restart a thread, 2. even if you can, the Animation will be handled by the system with different threads each running independently anyway.

How should I do this?

Let me narrate my goal again: I tap on a view, it starts blinking, fade in fade out style, using a method I wrote. Then I tap on another, both blinking at the same pace, with the first one perhaps noticeably changes its original blinking pace to be in sync with the 2nd one. Then I tap on another, another... no matter how many I enable blinking animation on, these views all fade in and fade out at the same pace.

Can you offer any advice? Either a specific one or a general one.

Comment: If you want to animate all views in the same way maybe you should try using `ValueAnimator` with a `AnimatorUpdateListener`. But you will have to do the blinking animation yourself.